# Only 2 of 10 fragments loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to load 10 fragments to a RelativeLayout inside of a ScrollView but only 2 are being loaded. The fragment code is below, it should work. There are 10 RIds that equal one DId (I am using dummy data) hence why there should be 10 fragments loading instead of my two. I have a feeling it is to do with the RelativeLayout not being able to take more than 2 fragments because its height is fixed to match_parent.

```
for (String DId: DIds){
    for (String RId: RIds){
        if (DId.equals(RId)){
            //RId found
            InformationPackage informationPackage = new InformationPackage(DId);                                            

            Bundle rBundle = new Bundle();
            rBundle.putParcelable("InformationPackage", informationPackage);

            RFragment rFragment = new RFragment();
            rFragment.setArguments(rBundle);

            String key = "rFragment" + fragmentCreationIterator;
            fragmentCreationIterator++;

            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.RContainer, rFragment, key);
        }
    }
}

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Below is the XML.

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:id="@+id/RContainer">
            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: change to linearlayout with orientation vertical..

Comment: Yes!!!! That fixed it! I love you so much. One thing though, why does that work? Once again, thank you so damn much.

Answer (score 0):

ZeroOne's comment was the answer, changing the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout fixed everything. I do not know why it works but there you go.